# DialogFragment Listener implementation in another Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, listener, android-dialogfragment

I have a Fragment which calls a DialogFragment, but it crashes in setOnSensorRateChangeListener.

This is how I call the DialogFragment from Fragment

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
SensorRateChangeDlg dialogFragment = new SensorRateChangeDlg();
dialogFragment.setOnSensorRateChangeListener(this); // here it crashes ->  java.lang.IllegalStateException: You can not set Dialog's OnCancelListener or OnDismissListener
dialogFragment.show(fm, "rate");
```

This is the implementation in DialogFragment

```
public interface SensorRateChangeListener {
  public int getRate();
  public void onRateChange(int delay_picked);
}
```

And I have this in the Fragment

```
public class SensorViewFragment extends Fragment implements
    SensorEventListener, SensorRateChangeDlg.SensorRateChangeListener {

***************************************
// Provide the current sensor's rate setting this method is
// defined by the SensorRateChangeDlg.SensorRateChangeListener interface
@Override
public int getRate() {
    return settings.getRate();
}

// The dialog fragment receives a reference to this Activity through the
// Fragment.onAttach() callback, which it uses to call the following methods
// defined by the SensorRateChangeDlg.SensorRateChangeListener interface
@Override
public void onRateChange(int rate_picked) {
    // User touched the dialog's positive button

    // Remember setting at chosen rate
    settings.setRate(rate_picked);
    applySettings();

    return;
}
```

Comment: I take it changing this to getActivity() in setOnSensorRateChangeListener doesn't work?

Comment: No, it does not work, because the listener is implemented in the fragment not in mainactivity